# Check if date is valid in js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my app, I am using ReactTimeAgo to display the date a message was sent, but when the user sends a message, I get .toDate() is not a function.
But if I reload the page after receiving the error, it will work fine.
Is there a way that if .toDate() is not a function I just return blank?
For example,

```
{msg.sent.toDate()?<ReactTimeAgo date={msg.sent.toDate()}/>:''}
```

But this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
typeof message.sent.toDate !== "function" ? "" : message.sent.toDate()
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and easy solution

Answer (score 1):

To check if an object is a **valid** date object, you can check if the object has date [methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#instance_methods) or not:

```js
const date1 = new Date()
console.log(typeof date1.getMonth === 'function')

const date2 = {
  a: 1
}
console.log(typeof date2.getMonth === 'function')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [`optional chaining`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) operator:

```
date={msg.sent?.toDate()}
```